# Reducing the size of the Xamarin Android App with Emgu library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, emgucv

I am using Emgu in Xamarin App.
 Xamarin dlls are 48.6 MB and Emgu dll is 62 MB. Totally
 around 110 MB. Which is more than the android play store size of 100MB. How do people submit Xamarin Android app with Emgu Integrated to Google play store.

Comment: Did you try linking to reduce the file size? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/

Comment: You will need to package for each ABI : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/build-abi-specific-apks/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't messed with emgu, but you could try:

- [Not linking DLLs you don't need](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/)
- [Use specific ABI](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/build-abi-specific-apks/)
- [Watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ro_ObZWtE1A) to understand what using different build options implicate